# Closing a threaded loop

Tags: python, serial-port, pygtk

The code I am working on needs to use a serial port event (connecting pins 5 and 8 with a contact switch) to trigger a function (playing music), within a GUI application. I have created a loop to monitor the serial port and have this running within a separate thread from the pygtk GUI.

I an testing this from the command line. When the GUI is closed, the monitoring thread does not immediately close. It stays open until the event is triggered (the contact switch pressed) again then it will close.

I do not want users to need to press a switch to properly close a program!

A simplified version of the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import sys
import subprocess
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import threading
import gobject
from serial import Serial
from fcntl import  ioctl
from termios import (
    TIOCMIWAIT,
    TIOCM_RNG,
    TIOCM_DSR,
    TIOCM_CD,
    TIOCM_CTS
)

ser = Serial('/dev/ttyS0')
wait_signals = (TIOCM_RNG |
                TIOCM_DSR |
                TIOCM_CD  |
                TIOCM_CTS)

def startplaying():
    #for testing
    print('Start playing the track!')

gobject.threads_init()

class SerialWatch(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SerialWatch, self).__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            while not self._stop.isSet():
                ioctl(ser.fd, TIOCMIWAIT, wait_signals)
                startplaying()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

class MusicManager():

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
        self.window.show_all()    

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

sw = SerialWatch()
sw.start()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    music_manager =  MusicManager()
    music_manager.main()

sw.stop()
```

I am not an experienced programmer and would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: The answer I have posted here earlier was wrong. The problem is that your thread blocks on the ioctl which waits for status change on the serial line. You could use the TIOCMGET to simply read the serial port status bits and return immediately from ioctl, sleep for 100ms and then check again. That way you will be able to stop your thread as it would never block indefinitely.

Comment: Ok thanks for taking the time to look at this. I will try your suggestion and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who might find this post and is interested in how I got things to work the way I wanted:

I did not want to use polling as smichak suggested. However my attempts to use threads to run the TIOCMIWAIT loop failed as it interfered with the GUI loop.

What I have done is to write a separate python script to watch the serial port with the TIOCMIWAIT loop and to run this script as a subprocess from the main GUI program. This way the script is launched when the GUI is opened and it is killed when the GUI is closed. When a connection is made on the serial port, the script uses dbus to communicate to the GUI and run the required function.